# Splitting data to training, testing and valuation when making Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm a little confused about splitting the dataset when I'm making and evaluating Keras machine learning models.
Lets say that I have dataset of 1000 rows.

```
features = df.iloc[:,:-1]
results = df.iloc[:,-1]
```

Now I want to split this data into training and testing (33% of data for testing, 67% for training):

```
x_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size=0.33)
```

I have read on the internet that fitting the data into model should look like this:

```
history = model.fit(features, results, validation_split = 0.2, epochs = 10, batch_size=50)
```

So I'm fitting the full data (features and results) to my model, and from that data I'm using 20% of data for validation: `validation_split = 0.2`.
So basically, my model will be trained with 80% of data, and tested on 20% of data.

So confusion starts when I need to evaluate the model:

```
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=50)
```

Is this correct?
I mean, why should I split the data into training and testing, where does x_train and y_train go?

Can you please explain to me whats the correct order of steps for creating model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, in training time (`model. fit`), you have two sets: one is for the **training** set and another is for **validation/tuning/development** set. With the training set, you train the model, and with the validation set, you need to find the best set of hyper-parameter. And when you're done, you may then test your model with unseen data set - a set that was completely hidden from the model unlike the **training** or **validation** set.

---

Now, when you used

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size=0.33)
```

By this, you split the `features` and `results` into `33%` of data for **testing**, `67%` for **training**. Now, you can do two things

1. use the (`X_test` and `y_test` as validation set in `model.fit(...)`. Or,
2. use them for final prediction in `model. predict(...)`

---

So, if you choose these test sets as a validation set ( **number 1** ), you would do as follows:

```
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_trian, 
         validation_data = (X_test, y_test), ...)
```

In the training log, you will get the validation results along with the training score. The validation results should be the same if you later compute `model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)`.

---

Now, if you choose those **test** set as a final prediction or final evaluation set ( **number 2** ), then you need to make **validation** set newly or use the `validation_split` argument as follows:

```
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_trian, 
         validation_split = 0.2, ...)
```

The `Keras` API will take the `.2` percentage of the training data (`X_train` and `y_train`) and use it for validation. And lastly, for the final evaluation of your model, you can do as follows:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=50)
```

Now, you can compare with `y_test` and `y_pred` with some relevant metrics.

Comment: but where is my model.evaluate then? What is that for?

Comment: if you choose number 1, and also if you set `x_test` and `y_test` as a validation set in the `model.fit` - in that case you don't need to use `mdoel.evaluate`. Because you can get the scores (`loss` or `acc`) from the training logs.

Comment: But if you choose number 2, where we don't use `x_test` and `y_test` in `mdoel.fit`, then you can do `model.evaluate (x_test, y_test)` and also `model.predict(x_test)` as shown above.

Comment: FYI, [In `fit()`, how is the `validation_split` computed?](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#in-fit-how-is-the-validation-split-computed)

Comment: Is one option preferable over the other?

Comment: It's better to pick option 2. Generally, it's always good to separate some data for final testing.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'd want to use your X_train, y_train data that you have split as arguments in the fit method. So it would look something like:

`history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=50)`

While not splitting your data before throwing it into the fit method and adding the validation_split arguments work as well, just be careful to refer to the keras documentation on the validation_data and validation_split arguments to make sure that you are splitting them up as expected.

There is a related question here:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38955/how-does-the-validation-split-parameter-of-keras-fit-function-work

Keras documentation:
https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/fit.html

Answer (score 1):

> I have read on the internet that fitting the data into model should
> look like this:

That means you need to fit features and labels. You already split them into `x_train` & `y_train`. So your fit should look like this:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.2, epochs = 10, batch_size=50)
```

> So confusion starts when I need to evaluate the model:
>
> score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=50) --> Is this correct?

That's correct, you evaluate the model by using testing features and corresponding labels. Furthermore if you want to get only for example predicted labels, you can use:

```
y_hat = model.predict(X_test)
```

Then you can compare `y_hat` with `y_test`, i.e get a confusion matrix etc.