# Difference between validation accuracy and results from model.evaluate

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to deep learning and I can't figure out what is the difference between the **validation accuracy** that you get at the end of each epoch and the **accuracy** you would get by using the `model.evaluate()` method. For instance:

```
model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset, epochs=1)
```

and

```
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1)
loss, scores = model.evaluate(test_dataset)
```

Would the two scripts return the same accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset, epochs=3)
```

By this, you are training the model with `train_dataset`, and using `test_dataset`, you evaluate your model after every epoch. So, after every epoch, the `keras` API will call the `model. evaluate(test_dataset)` and give you the training logs in the following manners:

```
Epoch 1/3
20ms/step - loss: 0.494 - accuracy: 0.8904 - val_loss: 0.6392 - val_accuracy: 0.8841

Epoch 2/3
16ms/step - loss: 0.1594 - accuracy: 0.9204 - val_loss: 0.5392 - val_accuracy: 0.9041

Epoch 3/3
17ms/step - loss: 0.0594 - accuracy: 0.9904 - val_loss: 0.2392 - val_accuracy: 0.9741
```

But if you do as follows, where you are not using `test_dataset` in the `model. fit`, you will then get only the training logs in the following manner.

```
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1)

Epoch 1/3
20ms/step - loss: 0.494 - accuracy: 0.8904 
    
Epoch 2/3
16ms/step - loss: 0.1594 - accuracy: 0.9204 

Epoch 3/3
17ms/step - loss: 0.0594 - accuracy: 0.9904
```

And after finishing all the epoch, when you do as follows, it will evaluate your model at one time (unlike three times before) and will give you the last validation scores.

```
loss, scores = model.evaluate(test_dataset)
[0.2392, 0.9741]
```

So, when you use `test_dataset` in the `model. fit`, this dataset will be used after **every epoch** by `model. evaluate` and give you the validation scores for every epoch but if you use `test_dataset` separately in the `model. evaluate`, it will compute only **one time**. Also **notice that**, in the last training logs, the validation scores are the same when you compute it later.

```
model.fit(..., test_dataset)
Epoch 3/3
    17ms/step - ... val_loss: 0.2392 - val_accuracy: 0.9741

----

loss, scores = model.evaluate(test_dataset)
[0.2392, 0.9741]
```

See my other answer, it might give you more insight. [Splitting data to training, testing, and valuation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67162399/9215780)

Comment: So is it the same or something changes?

Comment: Not exactly. In the first approach, it's more possible that you use this validation set using the `.fit` method to get some optimal hyper-parameter. For example, you may use `reduce_learning_rate` or `early_stopping` callback by monitoring the validation metrics.

Comment: But otherwise, normally the result would be the same.

Comment: @jackve see the updated answer, hope it will be clear to you now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the two will return the same, however they are used for different purposes.

Normally you wouldn't `evaluate` the validation set. Instead you would evaluate another set, the test_set, however in your case it would seem you only have a train and a test_dataset, and so both methods (the final epoch for method in `.fit`) will output the same accuracy.

The `validation_data` parameter is used to output accuracy/loss metrics **as the model trains**, to give you some perspective on how the model is learning over time on data that it doesn't adjust the model weights for, i.e. "unseen" data.

However, given that you look at these results, and tweak your model to try and obtain the best validation accuracy/loss, you have introduced some level of bias and so you might get an over-optimistic impression of how the model performs on truly unseen data - think about it, you're optimising for that very specific validation set so another dataset is likely to give different results.

So it makes sense to then keep aside another set, the `test_dataset`, which you haven't optimised for, but still would like to be able to say "my model delivers an accuracy of X%" or get a generalised opinion of how the model performs. This is where `model.evaluate` comes in, as it is a method you can use to see accuracies without having to call `model.fit` again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I still have one doubt: does the validation dataset have an impact on the final model? I mean, will the model have better accuracy on the validation dataset at the end if during the training I don't tune any hyper-parameter on the validation dataset?

Comment: No the only thing that actually impacts the model is the loss from the training set. You can use any accuracy metric or no validation set at all and the model will still learn the same, but the question is then how do you interpret the results yourself and determine how to make improvements.